# Checking presentation of work

Tags: summation

I am evaluating the following summation, $$\sum_{r=0}^9 (r^3 - 1)$$
and I have gotten $$\sum_{r=1}^9 r^3 - \sum_{r=1}^91 = \frac{1}{4} \cdot 9^2 \cdot (9+1)^2 - 9 = 2016$$ 
Is this the correct way to express my solution? Please correct me if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Small error, $\sum_0^9 1=10$.

Comment: The answer's nearly correct, but the title isn't appropriate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas there was a typing error. I actually converted r=0 into r=1 so does that mean I should use $\sum_{r=1}^{10} 1 = 10$ instead?

Comment: Yes, if you like $\sum_{r=0}^9 1=\sum_{s=1}^{10}$. In either case you are adding up ten $1$'s and get $10$.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be, $$\sum_{r=1}^9 r^3 - \sum_{r=1}^{10}1 = \frac{1}{4}\cdot9^2\cdot(9+1)^2 - 10 = 2015$$

Since $$\sum_{r=0}^91 = \sum_{r=1}^{10} 1 $$ not $$\sum_{r=0}^91 = \sum_{r=1}^91$$